# Changing the range of addresses served to clients connected via Internet Sharing

Tags: macos, network, airport, internet-sharing

Macbook Pro Running 10.7.4 attempting to share ethernet connection via Airport(Wi-Fi) and trying to serve 192.168.1.x addresses to connected clients.

I've tried the guidance provided [here](http://omegadelta.net/2011/04/29/changing-mac-os-x-snow-lepoards-internet-sharing-ip-range/) *(Dead link as of June 2016)* and the  article [Mac OS Hints: Change the default subnet for Internet Sharing](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090510120814850)
My `com.apple.nat` file has the following:

```
NAT =     {
    AirPort =         {
        40BitEncrypt = 0;
        Channel = 0;
        Enabled = 0;
        Extreme = "";
        NetworkName = *****;
        NetworkPassword = <*****>;
    };
    Enabled = 1;
    NatPortMapDisabled = 0;
    PrimaryInterface =         {
        Device = en0;
        Enabled = 0;
        HardwareKey = "";
        PrimaryUserReadable = Ethernet;
    };
    PrimaryService = "352E1799-A5BD-45F7-8C1C-49A963899CFC";
    SharingDevices =         (
        en1
    );
    SharingNetworkNumberStart = "192.168.1.0";
};
```

But no dice. `ifconfig` still shows en1 as 10.0.2.1
I've rebooted, made sure System Preferences was closed. en1 up'd and down'd

I'm guessing I need to be modifying a different file. I've looked at the binary for **InternetSharing** but it has way too much cruft in the file for me to confidently edit it.

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: I dug into this a while back: not a complete answer, but perhaps some useful details... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135163/22953

Answer (score 4):

This is specifically for Ethernet > Ethernet Sharing connections, rather than WiFi (it *might* work for WiFi but I haven't tested) - I thought the answer would best belong here, for Google.

Tested as working up to El Capitan 10.11.5

Apparently since Yosemite, adding just the `SharingNetworkNumberStart` key is no longer sufficient.
Also, System Prefs caches the NAT file located at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat` & will just overwrite your settings again, if you do things in the wrong order.
*Actual addresses are, of course, your choice.*

- Switch off internet Sharing.
  Close System Prefs
- In Terminal type these 3 commands

  ```
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberStart 192.168.0.0
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberEnd 192.168.0.20
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkMask 255.255.255.0
  ```
- Open System Prefs > Network
  Select what is to be your shared port & set as follows

  Configure IPv4: Manually
  IP Address: 192.168.0.1
  Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
  Router: 192.168.0.1
  Then in Advanced... > DNS add the same Router Address as DNS server, in this case 192.168.0.1

  OK, Apply.
- Switch on Internet Sharing

Test your Bridge address in Terminal with `ifconfig -a`  & check the line `inet 192.168.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255` is what you expected.

Info worked from [Mac OS Hints: Change the default subnet for Internet Sharing](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090510120814850)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, as you say, you need to modify the **InternetSharing** file, adding:

```
<key>AirPort</key>
        <dict>
            <key>40BitEncrypt</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Channel</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Enabled</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Extreme</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>NetworkName</key>
            <string>imacnet</string>
            <key>NetworkPassword</key>
            <data>cwB0AHUAYQByAA==</data>
            <key>SharingNetworkNumberStart</key>
            <string>10.0.99.0</string>
        </dict>
```

It seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: I wish it were as straight forward as it appears. The InternetSharing file mentioned is a binary file and not an easily editable plist. Looking at it with vim is a mess. The standard InternetSharing.plist file does not appear to manage the Airport configuration. Instead it has an argument which called the InternetSharing binary file. I'm looking for a clean way to edit the binary file.

Comment: You are right, it's a hell of a mess. Couldn't try it until now. I'll keep searching, though.

Comment: You change the `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist`, which is plain text, not the Internet Sharing file in `/usr/libexec/`. I added a new answer for how to do this for Ethernet rather than Wifi, if someone wants to tweak to suit for Wifi too.