how to change private IPV4 network used for network sharing?
I know how to share internet connection.
Now, when sharing internet connection, macos creates a private network, say 192.168.2.0/24 for IPV4, to be used by the machines that I share my internet access with.
When this private network conflicts with a network also used on the site you are on, how to force macos to use something different ?

Do you have other devices on your LAN using the 192.168.2.0/24 address range?

Yes, in fact there are tons of servers deployed by the IT staff in that IPV4 range. I lost connectivity with one particular server and it took me some time to realise that it was due to the fact I was sharing my ethernet connection vi WIFI, and macos was suddenly routing all packets to the guest NIC instead of the main ehernet NIC. :-(

Erratum. Instead of "and macos was suddenly routing all packets to the guest NIC", read "and macos was suddenly routing all 192.168.2.0/24 packets to the guest NIC"

Erratum 2. "Yes, in fact...." is not quite the right answer. This IP range is used on the site I work, there are servers etc... It's not technically on the LAN the mac uses, but on another LAN on the same site.

This is very old, but the first answer may be the method you need https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52479/changing-the-range-of-addresses-served-to-clients-connected-via-internet-sharing

That seems promising, thanks. Going to test in 12 hours from now.

I tried sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat N.... from apple.se. It did not work at all. I'm running mac os 15.11 sequoia. Maybe this stopped working at some point in the past.

192.168.x.x is a private non-(internet)-routable ip address range. In other words, you don’t have to worry about that happening because the IP address that other sites see is actually the IP address of your home router from AT&T Verizon or whoever.
There are other non-routable IP address ranges But that is the most common one used in home setups and small businesses.
But all you need to know, is that the IP address that is being used by you cannot possibly interfere with any other network.

I know what RFC 1918 IPV4 are. Those IP are private but it does'nt mean they're non-routable. They must not "escape" on the public internet, but you can route them internally. Organizations usually use 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/12 and let 192.168.0.0/16 free for "personnal use". Sadly, at my site, the IT staff chose to use this range for servers. The IP my mac has on that site is in the 172.16.0.0/12 range, it's NATed to get out on the internet, and some servers are on 192.168.0.0/16. Internal routing happens here. It's working fine. But there are edge cases like this one.
